# VAST Flash Video Ad not playing in Chrome with Video.js

Tags: css, flash, video, video.js, vast

Using the example from [the Onion's VAST plugin for Video.js](https://github.com/theonion/videojs-vast-plugin), I switched out the VAST xml file for one of my own which has a flash video for the ad's video source. When I play this in Chrome, I see the video start to play for a split second, then it stops and goes black. The error is:

```
Video.js: currentTime unavailable on Flash playback technology element.
```

The weird thing is that this setup works perfectly in Safari 8 on OSX.

Any ideas on what's going on here?

**Update:** Found the source of the problem is coming from my not including the videoJS CSS. Once I put that back in, the flash video ad plays again. **How can not including CSS break this?** Again, not including this CSS only breaks the playback on Chrome.

Comment: @akmozo It's an FLV video. when I try the demo in chrome the text turns red and nothing plays. In safari, i get a error message on the video player "Sorry, no compatible source and playback technology were found for this video. Try using another browser like Chrome or download the latest Adobe Flash Player"

Comment: what's weird is that the video plays fine in Safari (in my code, not example). I'm thinking there is a bug in the VAST plugin that has to do with switching between video technologies

Comment: the demo by itself works, but when i put in my VAST file with the FLV it breaks it on all browsers i have tested (windows: IE and Chrome, OSX: safari and chrome). Here's an issue i found on their github that seems similar to my issue: https://github.com/theonion/videojs-vast-plugin/issues/60

Comment: @akmozo - here's my vast file: http://img.mediaplex.com/content/0/14460/WBug_Original_15_Cutdown_640x480_15sec_VAST.xml

Comment: @akmozo what OS and browser are you on?

Comment: I also can't reproduce. akmozo's example works fine for me every time on Firefox 35 and Chrome 40 on OS X. Do you have a different link where you can reliably reproduce this?

Comment: @akmozo I updated the question with a new discovery we made in my app code.

Comment: @akmozo any idea why CSS is breaking the video playback in Chrome?

Comment: @akmozo the main videoJS CSS: http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.7.1/video-js.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script is crashing when the `video` element is not absolutely positioned. I haven't dug deeply enough to figure out exactly what the dependency is, but I'm pretty sure it's to do with the updating of the text in the "Skip in 5...4..." button. In fact your "split second" is exactly a second - it plays until the countdown tries to advance, and then throws an exception.

If you include this style the video will play

```
.vjs-tech { position: absolute; top:30px }
```

(the `top: 30px` is just so the video doesn't cover the play button - it still works with just the `position: absolute`, but it's harder to find the button)

Comment: adding that style in (with no other stylesheets included) DID allow the video to play. but i still don't understand why. When i don't have any CSS, i can still see the "skip in 5...4..." text unformatted below the video, and in Safari, i can click that text when it reaches 0 and the it does skip the ad. Why does it only break the playback in Chrome? And how does CSS make the JS crash while setting the skip label?

Comment: I started debugging it, but it's not immediately obvious so more digging would be required to find out for sure. My initial guess was that it's using the absolute position of the video to calculate the position for another element, and differences in the way browsers deal with offsets of non-absolute elements are causing the issue. I didn't find any evidence of this though, and it could equally be that the exception occurs in both browsers, but differences in uncaught exception handling mean Chrome aborts the video and Safari doesn't. Again, a guess. Possibly a bug in Video.js or the plugin.